# Have your chrome extension's stylesheets overwrite the site's CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension to modify the CSS of a specific page. Although, when I try to apply styles using `style.min.css` my spreadsheet is rendered before the site's spreadsheet in the cascade. To be precise, my rules are computed before theirs so their rules override mine.

For example, if I try this

```css
article {
    background-color: red;
}
```

their rule gets computed last and my background won't be red.

This is what the dev tools look like. We can see my injected stylesheet doesn't have priority in the cascade.

[image: Chrome dev tools]

Also this is my `manifest.json` without the project description and name.

```
"content_scripts": [{
      "css": ["style.min.css"],
      "js": ["main.js"],
      "matches": ["https://intra.epitech.eu/*"]
 }],
 "permissions": ["tabs"]
```

So if anyone has any idea on how to go around that by prioritising your styles in a chrome extension please leave a comment :)

Comment: You could use Javascript to inject a `<style>` tag after the page has loaded

Comment: @GarthBaker I have no idea where you commented or answered on my post and where you're getting your complaint from, besides it's been 6 hours and the problem only concerns me I guess ?

Comment: I posted an answer for you. but you didn't reply to after even 3 answers. So I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
article {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

The !important tag stops other styles from overriding your styles.

You should use the !important tag lightly though. Because if you over use it you will start running into conflicting styles when your CSS file becomes very big.

Answer (score 1):

More specific rules override more general ones (https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade) :

```
#homeboard section article {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried the first option which doesn't work as my styles get computed last. As to putting everything as !important that'd be tideous and extremely bad practice

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP comments `"run_at": "document_end"` works only for js files.
So load js file at document end then insert css files dynamically by loading css files from that js file.

In `manifest.json` write this

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["main.js"],
      "matches": ["https://intra.epitech.eu/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't work. I'm going to document myself on this tag though.

Comment: Read the doc. It states that the run_at rule only applies to js files. Although I'm going to be using this to load css files when the DOM is "ready"

Comment: sorry, maybe you could write chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab_id,     { file: 'file.css' });
Personally, I write web components in shadow root.